# Formulario Python en Negro

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple formulario en Tkinter pero al ejecutar siempre el fondo del mismo es negro, tal como se muestra en la imagen más abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código completo

```
from curses import window
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class Product:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Cosulta de productos')

        #Creating a frame container
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Nuevo producto')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

        #Name input
        Label(frame, text='Nombre: ').grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.geometry('300x300')
    window.configure(background='blue')
    window.mainloop()
```

Que podría estar haciendo mal? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: A mi (probado en windows 11) me funciona perfecto. Con el fondo azul. Estás seguro de que no solucionaste tu problema mientras creabas el [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Te juro que lo acabo de probar otra vez y el mismo drama, lo que me hace suponer que es un problema con el Sistema Operativo (Macos)